# Search box with live search like 'Questions that may already have your answer'?

Tags: feature-request

The 'Questions that may already have your answer' is very useful when you type a question, because a similar question almost always comes up. So can cant we replace th existent search box with one that has these results coming up live?

I know its easy to search in Google because almost all legitimate problems will fetch a SE/other sites result.

But it just isn't so SOic!

Comment: The box [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) does what you need. I like the idea, but I just think it would clutter up the UI a bit. I'm not sure where we could put it.

Comment: It's a bit of a pain to reach that page, isn't it? :P 
The search bar expands when you start typing in. You could make it show the results in a dropdown box, or so.